# How do I use MAAS and Juju with an existing DHCP server?

Tags: networking, server, juju, maas, cloud

I found some information about installing ubuntu with MaaS and JuJu, and I would like to try it out however I am not finding any information on how to take in to account a DHCP server already in the network.

I need to be able to configure this to use the existing DHCP as it is on a router that is already working. Is this possible? I did find some information about it and how to configure it but it was for ISC DHCP Server. I am not sure how it will apply in this situation. But it appears that the DHCP and DNS Server work in tandem in order for MaaS and JuJu to work properly.

Does anyone know of any documentation or information I can use to work with my current DHCP Server.

Answer (score 7):

You may refer to Manual DHCP configuration in the following link

- https://docs.maas.io/2.1/en/installconfig-network-dhcp#external-dhcp-and-a-reserved-ip-range

There is also a nice document by DELL (Deploying workloads with Juju and MAAS) where you can find a section for using an existing DNS/DHCP server and you can find it here

- http://linux.dell.com/files/whitepapers/Deploying_Workloads_With_Juju_And_MAAS.pdf

Comment: the first link is broken - wondering if this means current version of DHCP no longer supports the same configuration.

Comment: cached version of the page here: http://web.archive.org/web/20140705024900/http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/configure.html

Comment: Updated link is : https://docs.ubuntu.com/maas/2.1/en/installconfig-network-dhcp#external-dhcp-and-a-reserved-ip-range

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Juju, and I'm just learning MaaS, but I did a stock MaaS install (from the snap) on a machine with a pre-existing DHCP server.

I just turned off the machine's TFTP server and let MaaS's rackd handle TFTP service for me.  Didn't need to touch the DHCP server, since it was already configured for PXE boot:

```
subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.2.128 192.168.2.254;
  option routers 192.168.2.1;
  filename "/pxelinux.0";
}
```

When I booted a new server, it just picked up the boot image from MaaS and once it booted, appeared in MaaS's Machine table and appears to be working normally.

Comment: Your scenario being special, as maas is on the same machine as your pre existing DHCP server. if they are not on the same machine, you need the 'next-server' option as described in the Dell document, referenced in the top answer